# Are Helicopters allowed near busy airports?

Tags: air-traffic-control, helicopter

Are Helicopters allowed near busy airports or any airports at all and if not why not

Comment: How would helicopters not be allowed near any airports at all?

Comment: The West Midlands Police helicopter is based at the busy Birmingham International.....

Comment: Define "busy", "allowed", and "near".  Certainly there are helicopters based at the local comercial field (Reno) which is moderately busy, medical helicopters regularly land at the hospital that's maybe a mile west of the field (crossing the approach if they're coming from the east), helicopters regularly fly between there and South Lake Tahoe, military helicopters frequently land there, or transit the airspace from the Stead National Guard base...

Comment: Like all other aircraft, they are not allowed to fly over the airport or cross into arrival and departure airspace without clearance. It is the task of the air traffic controls to deconflict the aircraft appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, helicopters are allowed near busy (and any other) airports, because why not?

Ok, seriously: helicopters in general are just as able aircraft as ones with fixed wings. General limitations for use of airspace may be in effect depending on airspace categories around aiports, but to my knowledge there are no airports in the world that would specifially prohibit operation of helicopters in their airspace.

Some private airfields may have restrictions for helicopters and other aircraft due to noise, but I'm guessing this is not what you are asking?